# Socket.IO vs. Twisted

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, socket.io, twisted

My idea is to build a simple chat application for iOS and Android. In any case, my question is related to the server-side. The best option to do a chat application, from what I've read, is to build a socket. Referring to the database, my intention is to use MySQL, which may also be important to take into account in order to choose one of the possibilities.

My question is, in terms of scalability, speed and security, which is the best option: building a socket with Python using [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) or with NodeJS using [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/)?

I guess that there may be other possibilities to build an efficient socket, but by now I'm considering this two. I'd really appreciate it if you could give me some advice.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. The "best" option will be dependent on too many parameters to answer in this format.

Comment: But, for example, in terms of speed, there's for sure an objective answer. In any case, it can't be bad to hear opinions from people who have worked with these libraries.

Comment: It would be bad because answers based solely on opinions are not considered useful on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @IOS_DEV There isn't necessarily an "objective answer" for speed, as that can depend heavily on your workload and what you intend to do. Furthermore, speed is usually one of the last concerns that you should have; if you're talking about a "simple chat application", you don't generally need anything particularly high performance. The real question is: would you rather write Python or JavaScript? And which one allows you to get a MVP up and running more quickly? My recommendation would be to spend some time trying each one of them out; put together a quick proof of concept chat app.

Comment: @Lix But opinions may reflect if an option is more developer-friendly or not, which is also important. Moreover, if someone has a concrete opinion about some of them, it can be based in a personal experience or a concrete aspect of the library. Whatever is the reason of their opinion, this reason can help me to choose one of the options.

Comment: @IOS_DEV - these are the guidelines and rules of [so]. We are not here to discuss their validity. If you have some issues or opinions on how the site operates there is [meta] - a site dedicated to discussing [so] and other sites in the [se] network.

Comment: Okay @BrianCampbell, I think I'll try both to see the differences

Comment: Thanks @Lix, I'll consider them more seriously for future questions! ;) Now, what do you suggest me to do with this one?

Comment: @IOS_DEV - suggestion to do with the post? I suggest you attempt to implement one of the methods you detail and only if you come across a specific problem come back and post about it including the problematic code. As it currently stands I think this post should be removed. This however is only my opinion.

Comment: @Lix OK, I'll use StackOverFlow if I have an specific question about code when I try to implement one of the options. I won't delete the question right now, I'll wait to see if someone has something interesting to say.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Comparing Twisted and Socket.io is comparing apples to a truck carrying apples. Twisted is a library that provides event oriented programming functionality to Python. In javascript that's merely javascript itself (be it node.js or a web browser or even rhino).

A more apt comparison is to compare Socket.io on node.js with Socket.io on Python. While there is one main implementation of a socket.io server on node there are several for Python:

- https://github.com/MrJoes/tornadio
- https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio
- https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio

(taken from the socket.io wiki: https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/wiki)

You can even implement your own socket.io in Python using Twisted if you want. The socket.io protocol is documented here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec. But that would defeat the purpose of socket.io - it abstracts away low level details of real time web communications and allows you to concentrate on writing your business logic.

On the client side you'd deploy the same socket.io script to the browser regardless of what language you decide to write the server in.

With regards to which language to choose: my rule of thumb is choose the language you're most comfortable with. You're going to have enough problems debugging your business logic. Don't complicate it by using an unfamiliar language.

Both languages are battle hardened (yes, even node.js which is surprising considering how young it is). Python for example is used in production on such high traffic services as Dropbox. Node is currently in use on such high traffic services as LinkedIn mobile.

Comment: Thanks @slebetman! Your answer has cleared me many things.