# How to Implement a Class/Database Listener?

Tags: javascript, database, cordova, parse-platform

I am using the Parse.com database service for a PhoneGap app we are creating. We have users that can mark themselves (First User) "Available" for their friends (Second User), and I need a way to listen for that toggle in availability on the second user's side, so their friends list can update without having the refresh the page.

With Parse, your interaction with the database is monitored by # API calls and Burst Limit (Number of API calls per second) so I need to only call the database for the change in status when it is actually changed, I can't keep a setInterval on otherwise it will make the burst limit too small for other user, or it will cause to many API calls for no reason if the status isn't changing.

How can I got about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [socket.io](http://socket.io/) with [intercom.js](https://github.com/diy/intercom.js/). The first one does the pushing to the client, the second one ensures that only a single socket is open by multiple tabs. Socket.io has multiple fallbacks on client side, it can use websockets, flash, maybe even long-polling I guess...

The server side should support sockets. By nodejs it is very easy. By classical http languages, for example php+apache just the long-polling will work I think.

Be aware that your data pushing application will be socket based and not request-response based, so it won't be part of you webservice. Probably you should only push, that the user list must be refreshed. So there won't be any duplicated code...

Comment: I'll take a look at this, I'll accept your answer in a bit if nothing else comes in. I appreciate it.

Comment: Looks like we are going to have to change to a service like Pubnub with real time capabilities... thanks!

Comment: Not necessarily. You can run 2 services, one for socket connection and one with a REST or webservice interface. So you don't have to drop your existing code, just write a simple socket api based on database triggers for example...

Comment: Alright, do you have any examples I can look at? I have never used socket apis.

Comment: Me neither, use google ;-) There are many chat application examples using socket.io...

Comment: It should not be so hard, you have to create a socket connection - user identity map, and if a database change is related to an user id, then you can push data through its socket (if it has one). So you'll need a server which is maintaining the connections and there is a socket interface you can use to push data. By nodejs this is just a few line, by pything I don't know... Prepare yourself that probably you have to program asnyc or multithread code, not sync code as usual with a http server...

Comment: Here is a nodejs example: http://vijayannadi.wordpress.com/tutorials/sample-chat-app-using-nodejs-socketio/

Comment: There is a python framework called gevent, which is compatible with socket.io.
https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio
http://blog.pythonisito.com/2012/07/realtime-web-chat-with-socketio-and.html

Comment: Are you sure that this small feature does worth the effort?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711517/socket-io-vs-twisted
Other python socket.io servers.

Comment: Hmm I checked it is not such a pain with gevent as I expected. Good luck!

Comment: inf3rno, for the small feature I wanted to implement right now, no. But for our big feature, yes. GPS has to update constantly, and this will help.